# Where did urls like domain.com/index.html come from and how to fix the 404s

Tags: html, redirect, seo, http-status-code-404

So for some reason, crawlers keep picking up URLs with `"/index.html"` in the end of an existing URL and reporting 404.

Examples:

```
domain.com/index.html 
domain.com/pricing/index.html 
domain.com/solutions/index.html 
domain.com/solutions/project-management/index.html
```

The thing is, on our website, we have for example `"domain.com/pricing"`. But we don't really have `"domain.com/pricing/index.html"`.

I'm wondering:

1. What's causing those URLs to be listed on search engines in the first place?
2. Is there any quick fix to redirect anything like `"domain.com/whatever/index.html"` to `"domain.com/whatever"`?

This has been bothering me for a while!

Comment: Are you using Apache ? If so, what's in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Some crawlers guess common urls based on already visited ones, and try those - you can't stop the crawlers from guessing. As for how to redirect, this will vary based on which web server software you're using - Apache, NGINX, Lighttpd, IIS, etc, so it's worth including that information in your question.

Comment: I think it's nginx. Here's what's in our .htaccess file # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option to do not allow Google index your page is add meta:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

To redirect, you have to do it through the cPanel

Comment: I want google to index domain.com/pricing for example, but not domain.com/pricing/index.html